# Dependencies manager - Composer

Tags: php, composer-php

Well, I started using the facilities manager for PHP Composer. I've done the Download and it's working. But added a dependency on composer.json file, and need to do an update. How can I do this for the command line?

PS: I know very little about how to use the Command Prompt.

Comment: Try composer update for updating, composer help for learning

Comment: Did you try reading the Composer docs or the many blog posts about Composer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you open a command prompt and execute PHP with a call to composer.phar and followed by the Composer command you want to execute.

You are looking for Composer's `install` or `update` command, to fetch the dependencies you described in your `composer.json`file.

It's just: 
`php composer.phar install` or `php composer.phar update` on the CLI.

You may find all commands and their options in the [Composer CLI documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md).